# How to update the value when page refreshes (Hard Refresh). Not navigating between pages in React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript

I need to reset the value when page refreshes (Hard Refresh). However value should not reset when navigating between pages.

I need to set isExpaned to false & here is my code

```
const handleBeforeUnload = () => {
sessionStorage.setItem('SessionName', JSON.stringify({ isExpanded: false }));

return '';
};

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
```

It works fine for page refresh and also resetting the value when navigating between pages, which I do not want to reset. How to achieve this?

Comment: What about refresh not hard refresh will it reset?

Comment: What do you using for routing in react?

Comment: Yes, it reset. I use react-router-dom for routing

Comment: You can store the state in context and if the page refresh. All state will be reset automatically.